# Add value in Object Ionic 2

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have an Object:

```
public countriesSignup = [{
    name: 'countries',
    options: [
        {text: 'Customer', value: '1'},
    ]
}];
```

My Final Object must be:

```
countriesSignup = [{
    name: 'countries',
    options: [
        {text: 'Customer', value: '1'},
        {text: 'Contractor', value: '2'},
    ]
}];
```

How i can add from Controller? I try this:

```
this.countriesSignup['options'] = [{text: 'Contractor', value: '2'}] ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mistake#1

You are using Array of object, so you have to mention index also

So it should be

```
this.countriesSignup[0]
```

Mistake #2
Since options is array, you should use push

```
countriesSignup[0].options.push({})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can directly use **`.push`** since **`options`** is an array

```
this.countriesSignup[0].options.push({text: 'Contractor', value: '2'});
```